# Calling a flow(starting from a particular screen) from another flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow(X) from which I want to call another flow(Y). However, the requirement is not to initiate Y from the beginning but from a particular screen inside Y.

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? [Subflow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_subflow.htm&type=5) is an element that can be used in a  
Screen Flow.

Comment: @TSmith but a subflow would start the second flow from the beginning right? I want to start from a particular screen in the second flow

Comment: In you subflow you can add a parameters like `initialScreenNumber` and use decision element to decide which screen to show.

Answer (score 1):

A [subflow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.flow_ref_elements_subflow.htm) element can achieve this, but it all depends on where you connect such element within your calling flow.

Here you can see a decision being made dependant on if a custom checkbox on the screen has been set or not. If set, we orchestrate a call to the subflow (child flow) which is another screen flow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a Boolean variable in both X and Y flow.

1. Set this boolean variable true in your X flow
2. At the beginning of the Y flow, add a decision element and check if the boolean variable is true and show the respective Screen.
3. Set the default outcome to follow Flow from the beginning.